# Lucene Query against a known corpus

Tags: java, lucene

My situation is this:

I am trying to look for some medical records. As part of refining my search I have built an index with 10k known documents. Theoretically, if I have the correct search I should be able to iterate through that entire set, search for each one and find it as the highest score document (and first).

Except, that's not the behavior I am seeing. 3/10 times the document I am looking for. Sometimes isn't even in the top 5. The reason for this is that the documents are all scoring the same. I know I have found the correct document because I give them all a unique Id that is not part of the query

Given that I am explicit with the terms in the fields I am looking for and I know the exact contents of the index, the top document should be the one I seek (Theoretically).

Specifically, I am trying to find a related document based on a field:icdXcode where that field is a space delimited set of values. Example:

icd9Codes:"123456 938547 029381"

In the real world I won't know the corpus and definitely will be searching with an incomplete code list. **Problem: I need to get the document with the most matching codes in a given code field** If anyone can lend some insight that would be awesome. Thank you stackcommunity

Now some code:

Document format:

```
public Document getDocument() {
    final Document document = new Document();
    document.add(new StringField("gender", gender, Field.Store.YES));
    document.add(new StringField("ethnicity", ethnicity, Field.Store.YES));

    document.add(new IntField("claimId", claimId, Field.Store.YES));
    document.add(new IntField("age", age, Field.Store.YES));
    document.add(new IntField("zipcode", zipCode, Field.Store.YES));

    TextField i9codes = new TextField("icd9dxCodes", delimitedCollection(icd9dxCodes, " ").toString(), Field.Store.YES);
    document.add(i9codes);

    document.add(new TextField("icd9pcsCodes", delimitedCollection(icd9pcsCodes," ").toString(),Field.Store.YES));

    TextField i10Codes = new TextField("icd10dxCodes", delimitedCollection(icd10dxCodes, " ").toString(), Field.Store.YES);
    document.add(i10Codes);
    document.add(new TextField("icd10pcsCodes", delimitedCollection(icd10pcsCodes," ").toString(),Field.Store.YES));

    return document;
}
```

And the search code:

```
private ConvertedDocument findDocument(Directory index, ConvertedDocument docToFind) throws IOException {
    final BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
    ConvertedDocument resultDoc = null;
    Set<ConvertedDocument> debugList = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    for (String tag : docToFind.getIcd10dxCodes()) {
        TermQuery icd10dxCodes = new TermQuery(new Term("icd10dxCodes", tag));
        bq.add(icd10dxCodes, SHOULD);
    }

    bq.add(new TermQuery(new Term("gender", docToFind.getGender())), SHOULD);
    bq.add(newIntRange("age", docToFind.getAge(), docToFind.getAge(), true, true), SHOULD);
    bq.add(new TermQuery(new Term("ethnicity", docToFind.getGender())), SHOULD);
    bq.add(newIntRange("zipcode", docToFind.getZipCode(), docToFind.getZipCode(), true, true), SHOULD);

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10, true);
    searcher.search(bq, collector);
    TopDocs topDocs = collector.topDocs();
    ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;

    Document document = reader.document(hits[0].doc);

    resultDoc = marshal(document);

    if (docToFind.getClaimId() != resultDoc.getClaimId()) {
        for (int i = 1; i < hits.length; i++)
            debugList.add(marshal(reader.document(hits[i].doc)));

        System.out.format("%b: %d -> %s\r\n",debugList.contains(docToFind), docToFind.getClaimId(),debugList );
    }


    return resultDoc;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the answer is to add the field multiple times with the individual values build your query as original. Below is the new doc creation strategy

```
public Document getDocument() {
    final Document document = new Document();
    document.add(new StringField("gender", gender, Field.Store.YES));
    document.add(new StringField("ethnicity", ethnicity, Field.Store.YES));

    document.add(new IntField("claimId", claimId, Field.Store.YES));
    document.add(new IntField("age", age, Field.Store.YES));
    document.add(new IntField("zipcode", zipCode, Field.Store.YES));

    for (String icd9dxCode : icd9dxCodes) {
        StringField icd9dxCode1 = new StringField("icd9dxCode", icd9dxCode, Field.Store.YES);
        document.add(icd9dxCode1);
    }
    document.add(new StringField("icd9pcsCode", delimitedCollection(icd9pcsCodes," ").toString(),Field.Store.YES));

    for (String icd10dxCode : icd10dxCodes) {

        document.add(new StringField("icd10dxCode", icd10dxCode,Field.Store.YES));
    }
    document.add(new StringField("icd10pcsCode", delimitedCollection(icd10pcsCodes," ").toString(),Field.Store.YES));

    return document;
}
```

This is part of a PoC so forgive the total trash code :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried close to the same version of your code, when I query they are ranked properly.

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.IntField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause.Occur;
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

public class IndexData{

    public static void main(String argsp[]) throws Exception {
        Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
        IndexWriterConfig conf = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_46,new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46));
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory,conf); 

        final Document doc1 = new Document();
        doc1.add(new StringField("gender", "M", Field.Store.YES));
        doc1.add(new StringField("ethnicity", "Asian", Field.Store.YES));
        //first doc
        doc1.add(new IntField("claimId", 100, Field.Store.YES));
        doc1.add(new IntField("age", 10, Field.Store.YES));
        doc1.add(new IntField("zipcode", 20148, Field.Store.YES));
        //add with all codes  - should be ranked 1
        TextField i10Codes1 = new TextField("icd10dxCodes", "123456 938547 029381", Field.Store.YES);
        doc1.add(i10Codes1);
        writer.addDocument(doc1);



        final Document doc2 = new Document();
        doc2.add(new StringField("gender", "M", Field.Store.YES));
        doc2.add(new StringField("ethnicity", "Asian", Field.Store.YES));
        //second doc
        doc2.add(new IntField("claimId", 101, Field.Store.YES));
        doc2.add(new IntField("age", 10, Field.Store.YES));
        doc2.add(new IntField("zipcode", 20148, Field.Store.YES));
        //mess the middle code with somethig different - should be ranked 2
        TextField i10Codes2 = new TextField("icd10dxCodes", "123456 000000 029381", Field.Store.YES);
        doc2.add(i10Codes2);
        writer.addDocument(doc2);

        final Document doc3 = new Document();
        doc3.add(new StringField("gender", "M", Field.Store.YES));
        doc3.add(new StringField("ethnicity", "Asian", Field.Store.YES));
        //third doc
        doc3.add(new IntField("claimId", 102, Field.Store.YES));
        doc3.add(new IntField("age", 10, Field.Store.YES));
        doc3.add(new IntField("zipcode", 20148, Field.Store.YES));
        //mess the first two with somethign different - should be ranked 3
        TextField i10Codes3 = new TextField("icd10dxCodes", "000000 000000 029381", Field.Store.YES);
        doc3.add(i10Codes3);
        writer.addDocument(doc3);



        writer.commit();
        writer.close();
        final BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();

        for (String tag : new String[]{"123456","938547","029381"}) {
            TermQuery icd10dxCodes = new TermQuery(new Term("icd10dxCodes", tag));
            bq.add(icd10dxCodes, Occur.SHOULD);
        }

        bq.add(new TermQuery(new Term("gender", "M")), Occur.SHOULD);

        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(10, true);
        searcher.search(bq, collector);
        TopDocs topDocs = collector.topDocs();
        ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;
        System.out.println("hits :"+hits );
        //print results in score order
        for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Hit["+i+"] :"+hits[i] );
            Document result = reader.document(hits[i].doc);
            System.out.println("Results :"+result.getField("claimId") + " => "+result);
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the output :

```
hits :[Lorg.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;@fbf107
Hit[0] :doc=0 score=1.125771 shardIndex=-1
Results :stored<claimId:100> => Document<stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<gender:M> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<ethnicity:Asian> stored<claimId:100> stored<age:10> stored<zipcode:20148> stored,indexed,tokenized<icd10dxCodes:123456 938547 029381>>
Hit[1] :doc=1 score=0.47349548 shardIndex=-1
Results :stored<claimId:101> => Document<stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<gender:M> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<ethnicity:Asian> stored<claimId:101> stored<age:10> stored<zipcode:20148> stored,indexed,tokenized<icd10dxCodes:123456 000000 029381>>
Hit[2] :doc=2 score=0.19050911 shardIndex=-1
Results :stored<claimId:102> => Document<stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<gender:M> stored,indexed,tokenized,omitNorms,indexOptions=DOCS_ONLY<ethnicity:Asian> stored<claimId:102> stored<age:10> stored<zipcode:20148> stored,indexed,tokenized<icd10dxCodes:000000 000000 029381>>
```